# aysnc.forEachSeries only iterates on first element if element value is passed into callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

The following code attempts to **use forEachSeries to iterate on an array** `"a,s,d,f".split(',')` and **print the elements per iteration via callback**, but the **only value printed is of the first element** i.e. a. It omits printing s,d and f. **How to get it to print all elements?**

```
var async = require('async');
async.forEachSeries(
    "a,s,d,f".split(','),
    function (el,cb) {
        console.log(el);
        cb(el); //<-----------    NOTE: VALUE IS PASSED IN HERE - "STOPS AT FIRST ITERATION"                  
    },
    function (el) {
        console.log(el)
    }
);
console.log('x');
```

Following is the output:

```
a
a
x
```

But if on editing the code to one not passing a value in callback, this prints all values plus an extra `null`.

Following is the **code and output**:

```
var async = require('async');
async.forEachSeries(
    "a,s,d,f".split(','),
    function (el,cb) {
        console.log(el);
        cb(); //<-----------    NOTE: NO VALUE IS PASSED IN HERE - "WORKS FINE"         
    },
    function (el) {
        console.log(el)
    }
);

console.log('x');
```

**output**:

```
a
s
d
f
null
x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so that beats my understanding of callback features, the first arg is apparently an being treated as an error. Following edit works:

```
var async = require('async');
async.forEachSeries(
    "a,s,d,f".split(','),
    function (el,cb) {
        console.log(el);
        cb(null,el); // first arg as NULL proceeds to all iterations                  
    },
    function (err,el) {
        console.log(el)
    }
);
console.log('x');
```

output:

```
a
s
d
f
in cb
x
```